# Can you change the delete flag from a NamedTemporaryFile after the file was created?

Tags: python, temporary-files

How can I change the delete flag from a NamedTemporaryFile after the creation of such file?

Why? While most of the time I don't need to keep temporary files, if I detect an error from inside the code I want to keep them in order to be able to analyse them.

Comment: Did you try?  It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anybody now googling this question, at least for Python 3+, changing `delete` after instantiating `NamedTemporaryFile` does not change its initial behaviour, because the actual flag is stored in a object called `_closer` (which is a `_TemporaryFileCloser` instance). See `tempfile.py` in Python, as the [official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html) don't mention anything.

So you either change this **undocumented** attribute:

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
# f.delete = False  # This doesn't change anything
f._closer.delete = False  # undocumented
f.close()  # the file won't be deleted
```

Or you always create with `NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)`, and then delete the file manually if you don't want the file anymore.

Answer (score 2):

According to the source code, delete is just stored as an attribute of the object returned by `NamedTemporaryFile`, so you can modify as much as you want before closing it.

```
f = NamedTemporaryFile()
# stuff
f.delete = False
f.close()
```

---

EDIT : this is true for Python 2 ; for Python 3, see Augusto Men's answer.